# Custom alphanumeric sequences in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

We have a need to make a custom id called "JobID" in our  postgresql database.  It looks like this

XXX-Y

Where xxx=company short id and y=job id.

So imagine if we had job 3 for Apple it would be

APL-3.

You could have the same job 3 for Microsoft and it would be

MSF-3.

So its essentially a combination of a 3 digit code plus a sequence.

Is this something you can do in Postgresql?  I mean I could obviously do this without a sequence but I was curious if anybody had tried this before?

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution is to store two columns, then you could use a sequence for the numeric part.